How can I make a user receive a notification using `awesome_notifications` even when the application is closed?
main.dart:

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
    null,
    [
      NotificationChannel(
        channelKey: 'Mederipan',
        channelName: 'Mederipan',
        channelDescription: 'Notificaciones de Mederipan',
        defaultColor: Color(0xFF9D50DD),
        ledColor: Colors.white,
        importance: NotificationImportance.High,
      ),
    ],
  );
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );


  runApp(MyApp());
}

Function created so that the user receives a notification after 5 minutes:
void scheduleNotification() {
  AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
    content: NotificationContent(
      id: 10,
      channelKey: 'Mederipan',
      title: 'Recordatorio sobre tarjetas',
      body: '¡Ahora puede practicar la especialidad de ${widget.category} con las nuevas tarjetas disponibles desde hoy!',
      notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.Default,
    ),
    schedule: NotificationCalendar.fromDate(
      date: DateTime.now().add(Duration(minutes: 5)),
      preciseAlarm: true, 
      repeats: false,
    ),
  );
}

The expected result is to be able to receive notifications from the application even when it is closed.
